# In my 7 bit adder the carry bit is incorrect and i don't know why

Tags: c++, binary

I have this function and everything works until a and b both equal 1.  When that happens the carry bit is going to 2 when its supposed to be only 0 or 1.  Is my algorithm wrong for the carry bit
    carry_bits |= ((a & mask) & (b & mask)) << 1u;

```
bool add7bits( unsigned int a, unsigned int b, unsigned int *carry_out, unsigned int     *overflow_out, unsigned int *sum_out)
{
if ( a > ( ( 1u << NUM_BITS ) - 1 ) )
{
    cout << "a value: " << a << " is too large" << endl;
    return false;
}
else if ( b > ( ( 1u << NUM_BITS ) - 1 ) )
{
    cout << "b value: " << b << " is too large" << endl;
    return false;
}
else
{
    unsigned int sum_bits = 0;
    unsigned int carry_bits = 0;
    // Use a mask to access the specific bits of interest
    unsigned int mask = 1u;

    // Handle rightmost bit as a half-adder (no carry input)
    // sum = a ^ b
    // c_out = a & b
    sum_bits |= ( a & mask) ^ ( b & mask);

    // The carry _out_ from this stage sets the carry in for the next,
    // that is, the next higher bit in the carry_bits value

    carry_bits |= ((a & mask) & (b & mask)) << 1u;

    // The remaining bits must be handled with the full adder logic. The last
    // adder in the chain's carry out becomes the carry output return
    // value of this function.
            mask = 1u << 1;

            sum_bits |= ((a & mask) ^ (b & mask) ^ carry_bits);
            carry_bits |= ((a & mask) & (b & mask)) << 1u; 

            mask = 1u << 2;
            sum_bits |= ((a & mask) ^ (b & mask) ^ carry_bits);
            carry_bits |= ((a & mask) & (b & mask)) << 1u;

            mask = 1u << 3;
            sum_bits |= ((a & mask) ^ (b & mask) ^ carry_bits);
            carry_bits |= ((a & mask) & (b & mask)) << 1u;

            mask = 1u << 4;
            sum_bits |= ((a & mask) ^ (b & mask) ^ carry_bits);
            carry_bits |= ((a & mask) & (b & mask)) << 1u;          

            mask = 1u << 5;
            sum_bits |= ((a & mask) ^ (b & mask) ^ carry_bits);
            carry_bits |= ((a & mask) & (b & mask)) << 1u;  
    // Handle bit 6 separately.
    mask = 1u << 6;
    sum_bits = ((a ^b) ^ carry_bits);
    carry_bits |= ((a & mask) & (b & mask)) << 1u;


// Determine the overflow by checking if a and b are both 1.
    bool overflow = false;
    if ((a & mask) & (b & mask))
        overflow = true;
    // ...
    //
 *sum_out = sum_bits;
 *carry_out = carry_bits;
 *overflow_out = overflow;
 cout << a << " + " << b << " = " << *sum_out << endl;;
 cout << "Carry: " << *carry_out << endl;
 cout << "Overflow: " << *overflow_out << endl;
    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're or-ing ALL the previous carry bits into the sum bits at each stage, rather than just the carry bit for the current stage.  You want

```
sum_bits |= ((a & mask) ^ (b & mask) ^ (carry_bits & mask));
```

at each stage, or the equivalent, simpler:

```
sum_bits |= (a ^ b ^ carry_bits) & mask;
```

Your carry out computation is incorrect -- it doesn't take the carry in into account.  You want:

```
carry_bits |= ((a & b | a & carry_bits | b & carry_bits) & mask) << 1;
```

Your final carry out bit is the 8th bit of carry_bits, so you want:

```
*carry_out = carry_bits >> NUM_BITS;
```

to write just that bit.

"Overflow" doesn't really make much sense here, as you appear to be doing unsigned addition (so "overflow" to the extent it exists, is the same as carry out).  If you were doing 2s-complement signed addition, you want the xor of the last two carry bits:

```
*overflow_out = ((carry_out >> NUM_BITS) ^ (carry_out >> (NUM_BITS-1))) & 1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was so helpful! I knew my overflow still needed work. I was just trying to figure out how the carry was supposed to work. Your explanation was amazing!

Answer (score 1):

The *carry bit* is 1, and it's in the second position, so `carry_bits` is `...0010`, or 2.

Comment: How would I get it to shift to 0001

Comment: @user2948878: Why would you want to? If you want to store the carry bit as a bool, store it as a bool.

Comment: @user2948878: And what do you want it to represent? What do you want it to *mean?* The first carry bit? The last? The AND of all of them? The OR?

Comment: I want it to end up being the last one.

Comment: @user2948878: ...or 0 if none of them were 1. So just keep a running AND. You might find it easier to use `bool carry;` rather than `unsigned int carry_bits;`.